# Stop logging downloads from repository on Maven

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

Is there a way to remove redundant output lines that informs about every small download Maven made from the repository. I only want to see output of the actual plugins.

Is there a plugin that is in charge of all this output that I can configure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can achieve by changing maven settings.
Only options i knw are `mvn -q` hides the [INFO] lines and `mvn -X` shows the debug messages.

You should look to save the log messages in a file ans then use unix grep command to filter messages which you want.

Answer (score 0):

To suppress downloading/downloaded messages in maven I use the following command:

```
mvn --batch-mode ... bla bla bla ... | grep -v 'Download.* http'
```

It is will suppress downloading/downloaded messages without suppressing anything else, i.e. the uploading/uploaded [INFO] messages, which anyone in their right mind would want to keep.